Angular computed() property is not recalcualted after component is destroyed and reinitialized
I have a simple login form where username and password are signals and then I have a computed property, which shows if the login button is enabled or not.
username = signal('')
password = signal('')

isDisabled = computed(() => {
  const username = this.username()
  const password = this.password()
  return username == '' || password = ''
})

I put console outputs everywhere and when I first load the page every change will show in the console and will show that isDisabled is recalculcated. Then I navigate away from the page and navigate back to it within angular (no hard reload).
Now the inputs still trigger the username and password signals to change, but the computed() function is not called anymore.
I'm using angular version 17.3.9 right now.

please share the html and stackblitz demo

You have a missing = in the conditional check. Please find below working example for reference.
If issue still happens, please share back stackblitz with issue replicated.
import {
  Component,
  model,
  Injectable,
  inject,
  ModelSignal,
  signal,
  WritableSignal,
  computed,
} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, RouterOutlet, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dummy',
  imports: [RouterModule, FormsModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `dummy
  <a routerLink="/login"> go to login</a>`,
})
export class Dummy {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  imports: [RouterModule, FormsModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `<router-outlet/>
  <input [(ngModel)]="username"/><br/>
  <input [(ngModel)]="password"/><br/>
  <button [disabled]="isDisabled()">submit</button>
  <a routerLink="/dummy"> go to dummy</a>
  `,
})
export class Login {
  username = signal('');
  password = signal('');

  isDisabled = computed(() => {
    const username = this.username();
    const password = this.password();
    return username === '' || password === '';
  });
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      { path: 'login', component: Login },
      { path: 'dummy', component: Dummy },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]),
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo
